# How to write a GUI wrapper for an EXE if I do not have access to the source?

Tags: c#, batch-file, wrapper, exe

I'm looking into writing a GUI which will act as a wrapper for testing suite that is currently a selection of .bat's and .exe's

How would I go around implementing such a wrapper? I've looked into (and played with) running .bat's and .exe's from within c# (see [C# ProcessStartInfo read Output "live" (Concurrent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14582794/c-sharp-processstartinfo-read-output-live-concurrent)) using ProcessStartInfo.

How would I go about implementing this? Some of the .exe's require environment variables to be set, is it possible to set these from within a C# app for any .exe that it starts?

Is it possible to replace the .bat's with actual calls from C# to run each of those commands?

Has anyone written a similar wrapper before?

Comment: This question is far too vague and non-specific to be answered in a  single post here, and you've asked things like "what might go wrong" and "would a better approach be" and "do you know of anyone", none of which are appropriate questions to ask here. (They ask for discussion and speculation, and those types of questions are indicated in the FAQ as being a poor fit for the format here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can fire the .exe and .bat files you need from the command line, then you can use

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("myProg.exe", "cmdParam");
```

to launch myProg.exe with the parameter cmdParam. From there I'd just knock up a WinForms app with a button for each program (or set of programs) that you want to run, and then in the click handler code you just launch them. Of course, you'll need to know the path to the files, but you can always add in some logic to check they're there before trying to use them.

If you want to get clever with it then you can hook the standard file open dialog to locate them, and then add a textbox to enter that string of commandline parameters, so then you can have:

```cs
public class MyBatchFile
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; protected set; }
    public string DefaultParams { get; protected set; }

    public MyBatchFile(string filePath, string defaultParams)
    {
        FilePath = filePath;
        DefaultParams = defaultParams;
    }

    public string Run(string params = null)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(FilePath, (params ?? DefaultParams));
    }
}
```

and you can have your program keep an internal `List<Program>` to store these. If you want to get *really* clever with it then you can add a method to serialise that list to a file, and then some code to read that file back in and verify that the files it describes are still there, and now you have a neat little program-launching GUI that can remember where your batch files and command line tools are and provide a nice easy interface for launching them. You could even add a way of grouping them in sets so you can run multiple things with one click.

If nothing else, this answer has explained why I always have a programming project on the go.

Answer (score 1):

> Some of the .exe's require environment variables to be set, is it
>   possible to set these from within a C# app for any .exe that it
>   starts?

use the [`ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx) Property

> Is it possible to replace the .bat's with actual calls from C# to run each of those commands?

For an arbitrary batch file no. This is because batch files can have control flow statements (`loops` and `if`). Of course for a given batch file you could hand convert it.